# Arduino incoming byte

Tags: arduino

I'm building a system using two ultrasonic sensors and sending data through Xbee. I'm using two nodes in AT end point, one coordinator in AT mode as well.

For testing I've used the basic Arduino example:

```c
if(Serial.available > 0) {
    incomingByte = Serial.read(); 
    if(incomingByte == 'H') {
        //DO SOMETHING
    }
}
```

It works fine for byte coming from 1 node.

How can I implement to check if `incomingByte` is receiving data from node1 *and* node2 at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

you can't. Serial is born to be used by only two pair, infact it sdoes not have data collision managment (that mean if the sensor write toghedere, you will get ureadable data).

you can see the xbee as a serial, but that has collision detection and resolve under the hood. So you can't have parallel message.

You can add to the packet the time of the reading, and usa that

Also you can't use two ultrasonic togheder without taking big precautions as they will affect each others.

Comment: I'm using the sensors in two different Arduino boards. A third board is used as coordinator. I though that could work implementing an array, i.e: incomingByteArray[2]; Loop() if(incomingByte[0] && incomingByte[1]){

Comment: xbee cant recive from more than 1 at time, but it has collision control. So you still wont have same time, cause it will collide and a new packet will be sent

Comment: Edited with the suggestion to use timestampat beginning you'll need to sync the time, but then it will be easy